# Angular UI router not working on chrome app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chrome app using `angularjs` with `angular-ui-router`.

**app.js**

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', [
    'ui.router',
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    console.log("This works fine.");

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'modules/login/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })

}])
```

**login.js**

```
foo.controller('loginController',
    ['$scope',
    function($scope){

    console.log("This should be printed on the console.");

}])
```

**window.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mycurechrome">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="components/chromestrap/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/chromestrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="modules/login/controllers/login.js"></script>

    <link href="components/chromestrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/window.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "icons": { "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 1000,
            'height': 600
        }
    });
});
```

On the `app.js` the `console.log("This works fine.");` is excuted, but the log() on the `login.js` is not.

I don't think Im using `ui-router` wrong but im skeptical because there might be a different approach for google chrome app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to navigate to the login state, if it is your default state try:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    console.log("This works fine.");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'modules/login/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        });

}]);
```